# Swift: Web service call with binary image data

Tags: swift, nsdata

[I am just starting to get my hands dirty in Swift. I do not have much experience with web applications so please excuse silly questions that I may ask]

I am trying to perform send and receive operations over http to call a webservices which accepts and returns binary (image) data.

Case 1. Send JPEG data from UIImage to web service 
I am approaching this as follows:

> Get JPEG representation of image in NSData
>   append this data to the URL string:
>    http://domain:port/call/binarydata_*to*_de3?bin_array=[binary data from image goes here]

To be able to create this *URL* string from image data, I need to convert NSData from image to String, concatenate it to the URL and create the session.

How do I go about this?

Case 2. This is the reverse of above. In this I will make a call to URL 'http domain:port/call/binarydata_*from*_de3'. In response I will get BIN_ARRAY (jpeg bytes). I need to be able to assign it to UIImage and display it.

Thanks.